# Golang: Как передать по ссылке переменную interface{} вместо *string

Tags: golang

Вопрос: как это сделать?
пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func MakeUpper(s *string) {
    *s = strings.ToUpper(*s)
}

func main() {
    x := "qwe"
    fmt.Println(x) // qwe
    MakeUpper(&x)
    fmt.Println(x) // QWE
    y := interface{}("asd")
    fmt.Println(y) // asd
    // MakeUpper(y) // cannot use y (type interface {}) as type *string in argument to MakeUpper: need type assertion
    // MakeUpper(&y) // cannot use &y (type *interface {}) as type *string in argument to MakeUpper

    // MakeUpper(&string(y)) // cannot convert y (type interface {}) to type string: need type assertion
    // MakeUpper(*string(&y)) // cannot convert &y (type *interface {}) to type string

    // ok, using type assertion:
    // MakeUpper(&y.(string)) // cannot take the address of y.(string)
    // MakeUpper((&y).(*string)) // invalid type assertion: (&y).(string) (non-interface type *interface {} on left)
    // MakeUpper(y.(*string)) // panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not *string

    // Works:
    fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(y.(string))) // ASD

}
```

зачем нужно?
хочу сделать структуру (user type), содержащую поле типа interface{}, и использовать это поле в библиотечных функциях, принимающих аргумент по ссылке.

раньше прогал на python - подобных проблем в принципе не существовало)
даже в java можно сделать тип Object и (String)x потом, к примеру.

возможно ли вообще это сделать в golang, и как?)

самым логичным и правильным с точки зрения синтаксиса кажется

```
MakeUpper(&y.(string)) // cannot take the address of y.(string)
```

Невозможно получить адрес - связано с тем, что string и interface{}, содержащий string, выглядят в памяти по разному?

как тогда быть? хранить в структуре универсальный указатель *interface{} ?

```
var z *interface{}
z = &x // cannot use &x (type *string) as type *interface {} in assignment:
       // *interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface
```

так тоже не работает. как создать аналог void*?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/badoo/blog/301990/ - данная статья помогла

Answer (score 0):

```
// test
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func MakeUpper(s *string) {
    *s = strings.ToUpper(*s)
}

func main() {
    x := "qwe"
    var y interface{}
    y = &x
    MakeUpper(y.(*string))
    fmt.Println(*y.(*string))

}
```

вот так заработало... (внезапно)